# styling the first element inside loop - ejs

Tags: css, loops, css-selectors, ejs

Using ejs, I have a `for` loop that builds few `div`'s containers and inside them some `hr` and `text`.

I want to target by css only the `hr` element inside the **first** `div`.

```
        <% for(let i =0;i < items.length;i++) {%>
        <div class="listItemDiv"> 
          <hr />    // target
            <p><%=items[i]%><p>

        </div>
        <%  }%>
```

*I know I can make an if statement and add another class.
I aim for solution with `hr:psuedo-class`, if possible

Comment: If this is the first child within its parent, then `.listItemDiv:first-child hr` does the job.

Comment: literally tried everything except this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've mixed something, the CSS for the first element would simply be:

```
div.listItemDiv:nth-of-type(1) > hr {
    ...
}
```

`nth-of-type(1)` selects the first matching element of the type specified (`div.listItemDiv`).

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```js
<% items = ["a", "b", "c"] %>
<% for(let i=0;i < items.length;i++) { %>
    <div class="listItemDiv">
        <% if(!i) { %>
        <hr /> // target
        <% } %>
        <p>
            <%=items[i]%>
        <p>
    </div>
<% } %>
```